# Static hashmap not working

Tags: java, hashmap, multi-module

I have a multi module maven project. In which I have initialized a static hashmap in a common module. I am inserting values in that hashmap in other module called controller and when I want to iterate that hashmap in third module then it gives null.

Here is my static hashmap initialization:

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer>   hmSimultaneousRequestTracker = new  HashMap<String, Integer>();

Controller module:
            Constants.hmSimultaneousRequestTracker.put(inputjson.getSettings().getUsername(),1);

Third module:
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : Constants.hmSimultaneousRequestTracker.entrySet()) {

            if(entry.getKey().equals(username)){
                if(entry.getValue()>0);
                {
                int value = entry.getValue()-1  ;
                    entry.setValue(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this I get hashmap null.

Comment: Can you make the static field `final`? That would avoid it being set to `null` accidentally.

Comment: but why its getting null and how i can make change in that hashmap if i will make it final.

Comment: Also, judging from the name ("simultaneous requests"), this code needs to be threadsafe. A `HashMap` itself is not.

Comment: Besides having global state beeing a anti-pattern I dont see something wrong with your code. What type of "module" system is that? Is it sharing the same class loader? Can you show the NPE, maybe you are asuming null in the wrong place. BTW this linear search for user name seems slow, why not use `hmS.get(username)`?

Comment: Thats just a sample.

Comment: @eckes Its giving null while using get also... problem is hashmap is null

Comment: The HashMap can only be `null` if you set it to `null` somewhere. Make it `final` and the compiler will tell you where. (and you can still `put` things in the Map, even when it is `final`).

Comment: @eckes: Even with different class loaders, every copy of that class will have a non-null Map (unless it is explicitly set to null again somewhere).

Comment: @Thilo oh yes, right.

Comment: Are you sure that's what is making the NPE? A final field that has been initialized cannot become null later. Please post the exception stacktrace and indicate which line of code it refers to.

Comment: I mean now its not giving null but it shows no values this is what i get { } in the print out statement

Comment: Nullpointer is also possible, if you have a static initializer in a referenced class, that tries to access that static field. A StackTrace of the NPE would clarify things a lot...

Comment: Could we have the code with class declaration? I would like to see the decalration of "Constants". We may need also to know what is the architecture of theses modules: JEE, Spring, other?